# Getting the div screen location in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I am working on a project using Leaflet. I want to place a label for objects on the map. I don’t want the label to appear on the map. I want the label placed above the map, but at the screen or div Left location from a latLng point.

I can’t seem to get the correct position using the functions available. Is there some example I can look at to give me insight? I would think Leaflet could do this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sounds like you would be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20790045/how-to-precisely-place-a-div-element-on-a-map-using-leaflet-js/38164780#38164780. Otherwise you might need to explain in more details what you are trying to achieve, possibly with some sketch and sample code.

Comment: I want to be able to place a label above the map at the correct left location. I added an image to the comment above. Lets say a LineString is on the map. in a div above the map, I want to be able to add text at the same page.left location as say the start of the line. I need to be able to determine what the left position of the start of the line so the label will line up the actual start of the line on the map. I am controlling the zoom of the map so It wont change after the LineString is added to the map. –

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is to leverage [the `latLngToContainerPoint()` method of `L.Map`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#map-latlngtocontainerpoint) - it will give you the pixel coordinates *relative to the map container* of the `L.LatLng` passed.

So create a container for a tick...

```
    <div id="topbar"><span id="toptick">↓</span></div>
    <div id="leaflet"></div>
```

...and use CSS to ensure it's on top of the map container, and has the same width. Then, run a function to translate the map point you want into an offset relative to the top-left corner of the map container...

```
function repositionEdges(){
    var offset = map.latLngToContainerPoint(geopoint);
}
```

...run that after map initialization, and after every movement of the map...

```
repositionEdges();
map.on('move zoom', repositionEdges);
```

...and finally, inside that function, shift the tick horizontally tweaking its style...

```
function repositionEdges(){
    var offset = map.latLngToContainerPoint(geopoint);
    document.getElementById('toptick').style.left = offset.x + 'px';
}
```

You can see a working example at https://next.plnkr.co/edit/60qrWND50mCOQ11T?preview .

This is just one approach. The specific implementation will be different if you're using more than one point, or if you want to use `<canvas>` for drawing the ticks.

See also the graticule, edge scale bar and edge markers plugins from the [Leaflet plugins list](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html). Those plugins contain implementations of similar concepts.

Comment: This did exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers about accepting answers, BTW.